# Displaying Document Version in SharePoint Search Results

Tags: document, sharepoint-search, version

How to get version in search results in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Map the crawled property `ows_UIVersionString` to a managed property like RefinableString00 or a custom managed property (ensure that its marked searchable, retrievable, queryable) if using SP2013 On Prem.

After that you can use this managed property like you use for other crawled properties like in display templates or Search rest api etc.

[image]